# Style waypoints with google maps API

Tags: google-maps

I have created an application that plots waypoints onto Google Maps and then using the API I show the root and navigation to each waypoint.

But I want to style each waypoint... specifically give each one a unique title. You can do this when you add a marker, but I can not see away to do this to a waypoint.

Are there any workarounds or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4):

It seems you can't style them. My solution was to disable route markers for the waypoints by setting `supressMarkers: true` on the `google.maps.DirectionsRenderer`:

```
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    suppressInfoWindows: true,
    suppressMarkers: true,
    map: map
});
```

Then, loop over your waypoints and a marker for each, styled however you like.